# RSA | calculation of private key given public key for a changed totient formula

Tags: cryptography, rsa, private-key

Suppose, we have designed a new RSA algorithm with:
[new phi formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcqSq.png)

*phi(55)= 55* product of (subscript: p|55)(1-1/p)*

[The actual formula can also be found here: https://onlinecourses.nptel.ac.in/noc18_cs47/assets/img/a2q1.png?seed=27767&url=assets/img/a2q1.png]

keeping all other parameters as actual RSA algorithm. If the encryption key is 27, the decryption key is what?

So far, all I could understand here is that n=55,
and thus the public key: (e,n)= (27,55)

How do I proceed with this?

How does the changed totient affect my calculations hereafter?

Comment: That's not a new formula for `phi`, that's the standard formula; and for `n = 55` yields: `phi = 40`. i.e., the prime factors of `n = 55` are `p = 5, 11`. `phi = 55 * (1 - 1/5) * (1 - 1/11) = (11 - 1) * (5 - 1) = 40`

Comment: You're looking for `d` s.t. `27.d = 1 (mod 40)`. You need the extended Euclidean gcd algorithm to find this. In this case: `d = 3`.

Comment: Thanks @BrettHale.. I am sorry if the question was very basic. I just got confused as I am still learning the basics of the field.

Comment: Have a look at the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)) description. You can work through some basic examples, or try it yourself by encrypting and decrypting a 'message' value: `m` in `0 <= m < 55`

Answer (score 1):

Info given in the problem is 
encryption key (e) = 27
value of n = 55

1.Factoring n into 2 primes ,55 =5 * 11;

2.

```
Determine the value of pi(n) 
  =pi(55)
  =pi(5)pi(11)
  =10*4
  =40
```

3.Solve for linear congruence 1=ed(mod pi(n))
  calculate it using extended euclidean algorithm from which is written below

```
 40x + 27y =gcd(40,27)
 40x + 27y =1
```

We can write 40 as

```
 40=27(1) + 13
 27=13(2) + 1
```

Now reverse substitution :

```
 1=27-13(2)
 =27-(40-1(27))2
 =27-2(40)+2(27)
 =-2(40) + 3(27)
```

Thus -2 is coefficoent of bigger int and 3 for the small which we take as d.
Decryption key is (3,55) . Here your totient formula effected the way we solved linear congruence.

Comment: can I use d' = d + pi(55) = 3 + 40 = 43 ?